# slurm srun with singularity does not number MPI ranks correctly

Tags: docker, mpi, slurm, mpich, singularity-container

I have a simple Fortran program that prints the number of ranks and the rank to the screen for each processor in and MPI program

```
   program hello
   include 'mpif.h'
   integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
   
   call MPI_INIT(ierror)
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)
   print*, 'Hello from rank', rank, 'of ',size
   call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
   end
```

When I run this program with srun (slurm 20.11.3), it works as I would expect it to

```
> srun -n 2 -N 2 ./h.x
 Hello from rank           0 of            2
 Hello from rank           1 of            2
```

I compiled the program in a docker container, and I use singularity (version 3.6.1-1) on my HPC system to try to run the same program in my container

```
> singularity pull docker://thomasrobinson/hello:latest
> srun -n 2 -N 2 singularity exec hello_latest.sif /opt/hello/hello.x
 Hello from rank           0 of            1
 Hello from rank           0 of            1
```

The host system and container both have mpich-falvor MPI.  I have the same problem if I make the container in singularity and not docker.  I have the same problem if I do `srun -n 2` without the `-N 2`.  I've noticed that if I use `mpirun --bootstrap ssh` instead of `srun` then I get the expected behavior (same as running the program on my host system), but there is a performance hit.  I've had this problem with other versions of singularity and slurm.

What do I need to do to be able to use srun to run my containers?

Comment: which `mpi` plugin are you using? IIRC `srun --mpi=list` does list all the plugins. Ideally, `PMIx` is installed and you use it (or force it with `srun --mpi=pmix_v3 ...`). if not, at least make sure the PMI libraries provided by SLURM are present in your container.

Answer (score -2):

MPI singularity is handled a little bit differently than normal. The [Singularity MPI documentation](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/mpi.html#batch-scheduler-slurm) uses sbatch so I'd test with that first, but I believe it should work with srun as well.

```
$ cat my_job.sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name singularity-mpi
#SBATCH -N 2 # total number of nodes
#SBATCH --time=00:05:00 # Max execution time

mpirun -n 2 singularity exec hello_latest.sif /opt/hello/hello.x
$ sbatch my_job.sh
```

You may need to do some additional configuration as well, but there are a lot of details on how best to do that in the docs linked above.